# In an array: is there a way to change negative, zero and/or infinite values into positive, non-infinite, non-zero **unique** values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In an array: is there a way to change negative, zero and/or infinite values into positive, non-infinite, non-zero **unique** values?

```py
def placeholder(x)
  x = np.array(x) # returns an indefinite but finite amount of items i.e [-100,..., -2, -1, 0, 1, ...,100]
```

Our correct values are all the numbers above 0 (decimals included), but the values 0 and below are invalid. (basically if I run this array `np.log(x)` I should not receive an error, i.e. x > 0)

But we want to create unique and positive values for the invalid items and keep the correct ones.

```py
[1, 2, 3, ..., 200]
```

```
# for example all -6 values are converted to 19999,
# all -5 values converted to 1832903 and so on
```

Your converted values should not be the same as the existing valid values

Comment: Do you want to replace the "wrong" values with "correct" random unique values?

Comment: @Koffee, is not really clear the correlation between the values in the #Before and #After, the values in #After seems to be random positives values. If what you want to do is to filter positives values in numpy array, you could apply a filter.
```arr = np.array([-1, 2, 3])
filt = arr > 0
new_arr = arr[filt]
```

Comment: @Gealber I am attempting to remove invalid values and adding a unique valid value to replace the deleted value.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes

Comment: Do you also have valid values in the original array? If so, new values will have to be distinct from each other, but also from the non-replaced, pre-existing valid values?

Comment: @gimix Yes, you need to keep the valid values without changing them, while changing the invalid values into new and unique values (so when you feed the new array into ```log(x)``` it will not return an error

Comment: To be honest I cannot imagine why you would want to feed random values to your subsequent calculations, instead of simply ignoring the invalid values, but nevermind. I believe `replacements = random.sample(range(n), k)`, with appropriate values for `n` and `k`, is your best option to efficiently get a list of unique values you can use for replacement. But before you actually use these values you will need to check them to avoid collisions with the existing valid values, so it will be rather slow overall